# Does anybody know how to add the remove button in a custom module (field type) with unlimited number of values?

Tags: 8, nodes, entities

I am trying to add my custom field/module to a content type. I select `Unlimited` for the `Allowed number of values` option in `Field Settings` and I am able to Add another Item, however there is no remove button. Furthermore, each time I edit the content; an extra (blank) field is added.

Comment: Both issues seem to be connected, your field is not able to detect a blank line and so doesn't know when to remove or not save a line.

Comment: @4k4 how can I resolve this?

Comment: The custom field type needs to return a correct answer in the class method  `isEmtpy()`.

Comment: and does that need to be in the FieldType FieldFormatter or FieldWidget?
 I'm not exactly sure how this error came about. All the other fields such as imagefield work fine. can you please give me an example/outline of how to go about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The custom field type has to implement a method which tells whether the field is empty (if the inherited default method is not able to do this).

For example for a numeric field:

[NumericItemBase::isEmpty()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Field%21Plugin%21Field%21FieldType%21NumericItemBase.php/function/NumericItemBase%3A%3AisEmpty/8.4.x)

```
  public function isEmpty() {
    if (empty($this->value) && (string) $this->value !== '0') {
      return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
  }
```

Comment: That didn't do it :(

Comment: Then you have to debug how blank lines are submitted. What happens with the value and why it isn't detected as empty when it reaches `isEmpty()`).

Comment: That actually did it. I forgot to change the value to my variable. Thanks a lot :)